# на чистом php нормально вставлять в html field value оператор if?

Tags: php, html

вот так или как правильно?

```html
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name"  value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['fields'])){ echo $_SESSION['fields']['name']; } ?>" placeholder="Enter Name">
```

Comment: правильно использовать шаблонизаторы

Comment: @ ordman пример можно?

Comment: @ordman Конкретно тут шаблонизатор не нужен........  junior - можно так: `<?=  $_SESSION['fields'] ?? ''; ?>"`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский спасибо